# #dom-to-image Export an off the screen div as image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using the dom-to-image library (and downloadjs library) to take a snapshot of a div in my website.

I'm using this method:

```
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('myDiv'))
.then(function (dataUrl) {
    download(dataUrl, 'myDiv.png');
});
```

The problem is that the div I want to export, is off the screen, that is, it has these css properties:

```
.myDiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    top: 0;
}
```

and the method exports an empty image.

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?
Are there any other ways of hiding a div from the screen that i can try?

I would like to avoid using z-index css property if it is possible ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a style that brings your div visible in the viewport before taking the snapshot.

```js
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('myDiv'), {
  style: {
    'left': '0px'
  }
}).then(function(dataUrl) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = dataUrl;
  document.getElementById('result').appendChild(img);
  //download(dataUrl, 'myDiv.png');
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 0;
}

#result {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" class="myDiv">
  test
</div>

<div id="result">
</div>
```